# How to retrieve data from html to esp32 through spffi

Tags: arduino, embedded, esp32, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

Through spiffs, I am able to host a web server in which I have created a simple form which asks for input from a user. I am facing an issue I tried many solutions, and I saw many articles, but they were using html in their sketches. So basically, I need to get the data from whatever the user inputs on that html form and it should be disaplyed to a serial monitor . I am using a Arduino IDE. Here is my code.

```
#include "WiFi.h"
#include "SPIFFS.h"
#include "ESPAsyncWebServer.h"
 
const char* ssid = "ramesh";
const char* password =  "rameshlike";
 
AsyncWebServer server(80);
 
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
 
  if(!SPIFFS.begin()){
        Serial.println("An Error has occurred while mounting SPIFFS");
        return;
  }
 
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }
 
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
 
  server.on("/html", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(SPIFFS, "/test_file.html", "text/html");
  });
 
  server.begin();
}
 
void loop(){}
```

here's my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>

<script>
    function message_popup() {
      alert("Saved value to ESP SPIFFS");
      setTimeout(function(){ document.location.reload(false); }, 500);   
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>




<form action="/get" target="hidden-form">
    Enter string  <input type="text" name="input_string">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="message_popup()">
  </form><br>
  <form action="/get" target="hidden-form">
    Enter Integer  <input type="number " name="input_int">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="message_popup()">
  </form><br>
  <form action="/get" target="hidden-form">
    Enter Floating value <input type="number " name="input_float">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="message_popup()">
  </form>
  <iframe style="display:none" name="hidden-form"></iframe>



</body>



</html>
```

The html file is loading perfectly on the web server. but I am not able to find resources to get that data and print it on a serial monitor.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple HTML form:**

```
<form action="POST" target="/someURL">
    <input type="text" placeholder="someText" name="someText">
    <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
</form>
```

**Simple endpoint:**

```
// add a handler to an endpoint URL
// in here the second param must match with the form action
server.on("/someURL", HTTP_POST, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    // get the param count.
    int params = request->params();
    // loop over the params.
    for(int i=0;i<params;i++){
        // get a reference to the param object at index.
        AsyncWebParameter* p = request->getParam(i);
        // print param values.
        Serial.printf(
            "name: %s\nvalue:%s\n",
            p->name().c_str(),p->value().c_str()
       );
    }
    // always respond to the client with something!
    request->send(200,"text/plain","Got it!");
});
```

Note that inside your form you have to specify the action, either GET or POST or PUT or something, and the target url which in this case is "/someURL" and inside that form every input should have a name attribute and the submit button must have a type submit.

Oh and one more thing, use LittleFs instead of SPIFFS. It is working exactly the same as SPIFFS but much faster and reliable. Also SPIFFS is deprecated and LittleFs is built in too.

Here you can learn from everything that the EspAsyncWebserver provides: https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer#body-data-handling

*This code is untested, just an example to show you some idea.*